# Numbers of elements of each prime power order in a finite Abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Given a group, say:

**Z**2 × **Z**3 × **Z**3 × **Z**9 × **Z**27 × **Z**5.

How can I find the  number of elements of each prime power order?

For order 1, the number of elements is 1 (the identity).

For order 2 and above, I am completely lost and my textbook is not much help at all. A simple explanation would be so appreciated!

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of order $2$ can only be in $Z_2$ and so there is $1$.

Elements of order $5$ can only be in $Z_5$ and so there are $4$.

The powers of $3$ require slightly more work. For example, elements of order $3$ are in $$Z_3 \times Z_3 \times Z_9 \times Z_{27}$$ and therefore in $$Z_3 \times Z_3 \times Z_3 \times Z_{3}$$ and there are therefore $3^4-1$ of these.

Can you do elements of $9$ and $27$ yourself? Ask if you want your answers checked and remember that every element of $$Z_3 \times Z_3 \times Z_9 \times Z_{27}$$ will have order a power of $3$ and that there are $3 \times 3 \times9 \times {27}$ of these elements in total.

Comment: Why are elements of order 3 in Z3 x Z3 x Z9 x Z27 therefore in Z3 x Z3 x Z3 x Z3?

Comment: I'm unable to do 9 and 27. I guess I just don't understand what's going on here

Comment: The crucial thing to understand is that in a group $H\times K$, the $n$th power of an element $(h,k)$ is just $(h^n,k^n)$. So, for your group, an element of order $9$ must be in $Z_3 \times Z_3 \times Z_9 \times Z_{27}$. Now consider $(a,b,c,d)^9=(a^9,b^9,c^9,d^9)$. For this to be the identity we require each component to be the identity. I hope this helps but it sounds as if you do need to ask your professor for  some easy initial exercises on direct products.